# Calling OpenCV trainEM function multiple times with different samples

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

For speaker identification I need to use GMM algorithm and I chose OpenCV library for implementation.

I have a vector member variable of `ml::EM` for each speaker:

```
std::vector< cv::Ptr<cv::ml::EM> > gMFCCVec;
```

And I have a method which simply calls `trainEM` for given speaker.

```
void train(size_t speakerID, cv::Mat& samples)
{
    gMFCCVec[speakerID]->trainEM(samples);
}
```

My questions can I call `trainEM` method with different samples. I have `cv::Mat data1`, and `cv::Mat data2`. If I call like:

```
 trainEM(data1);
 trainEM(data2);
```

will `ml::EM` be trained with both `data1` and `data2`. Or the training result of the last one will override the first one (in this case `ml::EM` will be only trained with `data2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Training result of the last one will override the first one.

---

You can see in the [implementation](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/em.cpp) that `trainEM` calls `setTrainData`:

```
bool trainEM(InputArray samples,
           OutputArray logLikelihoods,
           OutputArray labels,
           OutputArray probs)
{
    Mat samplesMat = samples.getMat();
    setTrainData(START_AUTO_STEP, samplesMat, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return doTrain(START_AUTO_STEP, logLikelihoods, labels, probs);
}
```

and that `setTrainData` calls `clear()`:

```
void setTrainData(int startStep, const Mat& samples,
                  const Mat* probs0,
                  const Mat* means0,
                  const std::vector<Mat>* covs0,
                  const Mat* weights0)
{
    clear();
    ...
```

and that `clear` just clears the previous trained data:

```
void clear()
{
    trainSamples.release();
    ...
```